# FUNCTION GET ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a function for a purpose, function is like that but it does not work.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FNLVDAYS 
  (@MONTH SMALLINT,@YEAR SMALLINT)
  RETURNS INT
 AS
  BEGIN
  DECLARE @LVDAYS INT

  SELECT COALESCE((SELECT SUM (LVDAYS) FROM LeaveTran  WHERE
       LeaveTran.EMPCODE=LeaveMaster.EMPCODE AND LeaveTran.LVTYPE=LeaveMaster.LVTYPE   AND MONTH(LV_FROM)=@MONTH AND YEAR(LV_FROM)=@YEAR ),0) AVAILED
FROM LEAVEMASTER 

 RETURN @LVDAYS
 END
```

Give this error:

```
     Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure FNLVDAYS, Line 8
     Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.
```

Comment: You have written select query in function which is not supported in SQL server. either you can select into some variable or temporary table then process it.

Comment: You don't seem to need the variable declaration here as you don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps...

```
SELECT @LVDAYS=COALESCE((SELECT SUM (LVDAYS) FROM LeaveTran  WHERE
       LeaveTran.EMPCODE=LeaveMaster.EMPCODE AND LeaveTran.LVTYPE=LeaveMaster.LVTYPE   AND MONTH(LV_FROM)=@MONTH AND YEAR(LV_FROM)=@YEAR ),0) AVAILED
FROM LEAVEMASTER
```